# ssl jdbc connection keystore not found

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc

I wish to use jdbc to connect to a remote mysql database that has recently been secured via ssl. I found a simple example java program to test the connection. The connection fails and complains that the keystore file can not be found. I verify that the keystore is indeed where I say it is in the code. At least I think I do. The test application looks like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.*;
public class TestMySQLSSL {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Connection con = null;
        System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");
        System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","c:\\LiferayStuff\\bundles\\liferay-portal-6.0.6\\tomcat-6.0.29\\jrel.6.0_20\\keystore");
        System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","####");
        System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","c:\\LiferayStuff\\bundles\\liferay-portal-6.0.6\\tomcat-6.0.29\\jrel.6.0_20\\truststore");
        System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","####");
        try
        {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/isc"+
            "?verifyServerCertificate=true"+
            "&useSSL=true"+
            "&requireSSL=true";
            String user = "*******";
            String password = "******";

            Class dbDriver = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            boolean filelives;
            filelives = new File("c:/LiferayStuff/bundles/liferay-portal-6.0.6/tomcat-6.0.29/jre1.6.0_20/keystore").exists();
            System.out.println("keystore " + filelives);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    con.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e){}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the first bit of the output  I get looks like this:

```
keystore true
keyStore is : c:/LiferayStuff/bundles/liferay-portal-6.0.6/tomcat-6.0.29/jrel.6.0_20/keystore
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
default context init failed:java.security.PrivilegedActionException:java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\LiferayStuff\bundles\liferay-portal-6.0.6\tomcat-6.0.29\jrel.6.0_20\keystore (The system cannot find the path specified)
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlyingexception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException
MESSAGE: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

The keystore file is there but I suspect there may be something wrong with it. I am running the application on windows. Are there perhaps permission issues with the file? Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Dave Semeraro

Comment: Did you try `/` instead of `\\` in the properties? And you do know you show the store password? :)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the database admin had blocked all but a single ip access to the server. Once my IP was added I was able to get the code above to work. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: I don't think neither the question nor the answer was a waste of time. I find that these situations are quite common, and anyway it is a good reminder to check the entire environment. Not one of us are just coding hello world examples.